# See the full list of ratings on Google Play's developer console

Tags: android, google-play

I searched a lot but could not find this information: where is it possible to see the full list of ratings on the developer console?

In the part "Ratings & Reviews", only the ratings that were created WITH a comment are displayed.

I searched everywhere but did not find where to get the list of ratings that were made without comments.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you open the app from your device, you have the option to see all ratings.

Comment: The answer from Mukesh Singhania is not true. Using Google Play app on an Android device does NOT show all ratings. In fact it only shows the ratings that were given in your language. And only if you chose "useful first" it shows all. Selecting "newest first" or "highest rating first" it only shows ratings with comments.